# What are reasonable noise/dephasing parameters for QuEST to emulate state-of-the-art quantum computers?

Tags: programming, qiskit, simulation, noise

The [QuEST](https://quest.qtechtheory.org/) code allows for simulation of quantum computers taking dephasing and depolarizing noise into account via one and two qubit dephasing and depolarization. What are realistic parameters for such noise representing the current state-of-the-art of super-conducting or ion-trap quantum computers?
Are there similar options as in `qiskit.providers.aer.noise` of the [qiskit](https://qiskit.org/) package (as explained [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5132/how-can-noise-on-a-device-be-simulated-using-measured-noise-parameters/5133#5133)) to get parameters for other systems than IBM Q?